# RegEx JS extract string matching criterias from another string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this type of strings:

```
url('img.png') rgba(123, 111, 23, 0.96) none repeat scroll 0% 0% / auto padding-box padding-box

url('img.png') rgb(123, 111, 23) none repeat scroll 0% 0% / auto padding-box padding-box
```

note the rgb/rgba difference

and I need to extract only `rgba(123, 111, 23, 0.96)` or `rgb(123, 111, 23)`

essentially, how to I select strings that starts with `rgb` and ends with a `parenthesis )` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `/rgba?\(.*?\)/` with `String.match` method; `rgba?` matches `rgb` or `rgba`, `\(.*?\)` matches the first pair of parenthesis after, which assumes you have no nested parenthesis:

```js
var samples = ["url('img.png') rgba(123, 111, 23, 0.96) none repeat scroll 0% 0% / auto padding-box padding-box",
"url('img.png') rgb(123, 111, 23) none repeat scroll 0% 0% / auto padding-box padding-box"]

console.log(
  samples.map(s => s.match(/rgba?\(.*?\)/))
)

// if have more than one matches in the strings

console.log(
  samples.map(s => s.match(/rgba?\(.*?\)/g))
)
```

Comment: it works!! i'm curious now...it only gets the first occurence of rgb/rgba... what if there were more than one?

Comment: You can use a global flag `g` to match multiple occurrences. `/rgba?\(.*?\)/g` should work.

Answer (score 0):

Along with the regex approach, you could also try something like this

```
var str = "url('img.png') rgba(123, 111, 23, 0.96) none repeat scroll 0% 0% / auto padding-box padding-box";

return "rgb"+str.split('rgb').pop().split(')').shift()+")";
```